# MS Access VB: How do I update a table with a parametrized query ONLY with textboxes that are not empty?

Tags: ms-access, vba, sql-update

I have some VBA code that will update a table based on a form. It works great, except that I want the table to only update wherever the user fill in info. If that textbox is instead blank, do no update that field in the table. Below is the working update code. The line that starts with `If query.Parameters("P1")...` is my attempt at trying to make an `If` statement that will find which textbox values are `Null` and then ignore those, but I don't know if that's even going in the right direction.

```
Private Sub Command133_Click()
    'Update row for downtime

    Dim dbsCurrent As Database
    Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb

    ', suffix, production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment              ,'" & CInt(Me.Text118) & "','" & CDate(Me.Text126) & "','" & Me.Text121 & "','" & CDbl(Me.Text123) & "','" & Me.Text128 & "'
    'dbsCurrent.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime (production_date) SELECT #" & Me.Text126 & "# FROM tbl_Downtime As t WHERE t.ID = " & Me.Text135 & ";"
    'dbsCurrent.Execute "UPDATE tbl_Downtime SET job = '" & Me.Text116 & "', suffix = '" & Me.Text118 & "', production_date = #" & Me.Text126 & "#, reason = '" & Me.Text121 & "', downtime_minutes = " & Me.Text123 & ", comment = '" & Me.Text128 & "', shift = '" & Me.Text144 & "' WHERE t.ID = " & Me.Text135 & ";"

    Dim query As QueryDef
    Dim sql As String

    For Each query In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
      If query.Name = "UpdateDowntime" Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next query

    If query Is Nothing Then
      sql = "parameters " & _
        "P1 text, P2 text, P3 Date, P4 Text, P5 Number, P6 Text, P7 Text, P8 Number;" & _
        "UPDATE [tbl_Downtime] " & _
        "SET job = [P1], suffix = [P2], production_date = [P3], reason = [P4], downtime_minutes = [P5], comment = [P6], shift = [P7] " & _
        "WHERE[tbl_Downtime].id = [P8]"

        '"(job, suffix, production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment, shift) " & _
       '" VALUES ([P1], [P2], [P3], [P4], [P5], [P6], [P7]) WHERE[tbl_Downtime].id = [P8]"

      Set query = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("UpdateDowntime", sql)
    End If

    query.Parameters("P1").Value = Me.Text116
    query.Parameters("P2").Value = Me.Text118
    query.Parameters("P3").Value = Me.Text126
    query.Parameters("P4").Value = Me.Text121
    query.Parameters("P5").Value = Me.Text123
    query.Parameters("P6").Value = Me.Text128
    query.Parameters("P7").Value = Me.Text144
    query.Parameters("P8").Value = Me.Text135


    If query.Parameters("P1").Value = "" Then Set query.Parameters("P1").Value = job End If ' WHERE [tbl_Downtime].id = [P8] END


    query.Execute
```

Comment: I am not sure about the fact that `Null`works to identify empty textbox values. Try using `vbNullString`or "".

Comment: check this : http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?684799-The-Differences-among-Empty-Nothing-vbNull-vbNullChar-vbNullString-and-the-Zero-L

Comment: @Fnayou thanks for the link. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

An empty string is not the same as a null value in a database, so you need to change the parameter value to nothing if you want it to equate to null (or default value if one exists).

You could either conditionally set the parameter value like this:

```
If textbox1.text <> "" then
    query.Parameters("P1").Value = textbox1.text
End if
```

or you could write a function to set the parameter to nothing if the textbox is empty:

```
Function NothingIfEmpty(value As String)
    If value = "" Then
        NothingIfEmpty = Nothing
    Else
        NothingIfEmpty = value
    End If
End Function
```

and use it like this:

```
query.Parameters("P1").Value = NothingIfEmpty(textbox1.text)
query.Parameters("P2").Value = NothingIfEmpty(textbox2.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
"SET job = Nz([P1], job), suffix = Nz([P2], suffix), production_date = Nz([P3], production_date), reason = Nz([P4], reason), downtime_minutes = Nz([P5], downtime_minutes), comment = Nz([P6], comment), shift = Nz([P7], shift) " & _
"WHERE [tbl_Downtime].id = Nz([P8], -[id])"
```